# Recognize long press in swift without UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I'm building an app around gesture recognition.
I've already built my code with recognition of taps, swipes (even with multiples fingers), pinches.

Now I'd like to recognize long press gesture without using UILongPressGestureRecognizer because it enters in conflit with my recognition of other gesture after (I tried).

What I'm currently doing is that I get the time in touchesBegan, in touchesMoved i calculate the time difference, and if it's greater than 400ms (for exemple), i call a function. 
The thing is that this function is only called when the finger moved a bit and not when it's perfectly static.

Another option is to set a kind of delay in the touchesBegan and check if the finger is still on the screen after 400ms and then call the function.

How could I do that without blocking the rest of the gesture recognition ? 
The aim of this long press would be to do a variation of intensity of a light or something like that (from 0 to 1s, light increase until max is reach, and then lower until minimum etc).

Next, I'll try to recognize a rotation gesture (with only one finger), so if you also have an answer for this, that'd be perfect.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set delay. Start a `timer` that will fire after 400ms. In `touchesEnded` invalidate the `timer`, in case it was called before 400ms. When the `timer` fires, call the desired function.

As to your second question, probably you will need to calculate the trajectory of the `points` in `touchesMoved` method. If somehow the moves resemble rotation (you will need some kind of threshold for that), call the appropriate function.

Comment: Ok, thanks, looks like it did the trick. Wasn't aware of timer. Havn't started yet for the rotation gesture. I'll see that later I guess :) Thanks for your answer.